Long delay after article was "Provisionally accepted"
I submitted an article around July last year to a IOPscience journal and after the first round of revisions I sent my response letter and my article with the suggested changes. Then after the second round, in October, the reviewers gave a positive response, recommending the article to publication. I got a "provisionally accepted" letter. I sent all my source files and copyright permissions. But it's been six months and I have no update, I have sent several emails to the editorial team and absolutely no response. I've been "ghosted" and I don't know what to do. I ask for some suggestions, have any of you experienced similar situation?

Not sure how you wrote "emails to the editorial team", but one suspicion is that there may be another email address out there that works better for contacting the relevant persons than the one you actually used. Maybe you haven't been "ghosted", rather the people who could help were not the ones who got your email? Of course also emails end up in spam filters or people have so many emails that they forget about some of them. I do accept though that getting hold of the "right" people is often not easy or even impossible.

What Is "IOPscience journal"? I thought IOPscience is a publisher, not a journal. What is the specific journal you're asking about?

In some fields, there can be a long delay between when the paper is accepted for publication and when it is actually published. For example, I had a paper where I submitted it in 2021, then after a back-and-forth with the referee it was accepted in 2022, but it was not published till 2024 due to the journal backlog. In my field (mathematics), listing a paper as "accepted" on a CV is the same as "published" for all intents and purposes.

I have sent several emails to the editorial team and absolutely no response. I've been "ghosted" and I don't know what to do.

This is a bit unusual. Be careful not to overwhelm them with emails, but it would be nice for you to know if there's anything else they need you to do on your end. I would try my editor first (whoever handled the submission), then the administrative support person (whoever got me to sign the copyright form), then the lead editor, then other editors I know on the editorial board, etc. But, in each case, I'd give a week or two for them to respond. Note that the administrative support person is probably the only one on salary. April is an extremely busy month for academics, so the others might not respond till May.
Another option for you would be to reach out to someone else who published in the same journal, to see if they, too, had a long wait. If they did, at least you know this is normal.
